# How to append data in delta table?

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Following is code which I've tried so far

```
import json
import csv

with open('/dbfs/mnt/costtransparency/HealthPlans/UHC/2022-11/2022-11-01_United-HealthCare-Services--Inc-_Third-Party-Administrator_Winstead_CSP-903-C746_in-network-rates.json.gz') as f:
    d=json.load(f)
employee_data = d['in_network']#d['provider_references']

# now we will open a file for writing
data_file = open('/dbfs/FileStore/data_file.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

# Counter variable used for writing
# headers to the CSV file
count = 0

for emp in employee_data:
    if count == 0:

        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = emp.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1

    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values())

data_file.close()
```

here is problem is currently I'm storing csv file into storage but I want to store it into delta table.

can anyone please help me to do this

Answer (score 2):

> **How to append data in delta table?**

**If you want to append the data into delta table use this following code:**

*First Read your Data frame:*

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/FileStore/vm_name3.csv")
```

*Then , append data into delta table by using write method at particular table.*

```
permanent_table_name = "demo123" #Table name
df.write.mode("append").format("delta").saveAsTable(permanent_table_name)
```

[image]

**Or**

*If you want to save delta table in particular location use this code.*

```
permanent_table_name = "dbfs:/user/hive/del"
df.write.mode("append").format("delta").save(permanent_table_name)
```

[image]